# LDAP Authenication on admin users?

Tags: authentication

I am new to Expression Engine, I am looking for a plugin or extension that will allow me to authenticate admin users against Active directory. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Devot-ee + Google = your friend:

[LDAP Authentication by Design by Front on Devot-ee (free)](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ldap-authentication)

As an aside, generally if you're looking for an add-on you are best off starting by searching Devot-ee first, as it basically has everything the community has released.

Comment: Thank you Tom,  I have played with that add-on and as far as I can tell that add-on only authenticates members not Admins against LDAP. I am looking for an add-on to authenticate Admin users only against active directory. Thanks